# Bundle value overwriting

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bundle

I have an activity called `ProductDisplayActivity` with a fragment within. This fragment gets created in the `onCreate` method of my activity like this:

```
ProductInfoFrag = new ProductInfoFragment();
ProductInfoFragmentListener = (ProductRetrieveInfoInterface) ProductInfoFrag;
FragmentTransaction InitialTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
InitialTransaction.add(R.id.product_info_frame, ProductInfoFrag);
InitialTransaction.commit();
```

In the fragment, through an interface, I call this function:

```
@Override
public void DownloadProductInfo(String ProductInfoDescription) {
    ProductInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(ProductInfoDescription));
    SavedString = new Bundle();
    SavedString.putString("SavedString", ProductInfoDescription);
}
```

I want to save the `ProductInfoDescription` so that when replacing frament I can recreate the view from this `Bundle`, so in `onResume` I have:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    if(SavedString != null){
      ProductInfo.setText(Html.fromHtml(SavedString.getString("SavedString")));
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Then I have an activity called `ResultsList` with a list of products, and on click I start a new intent calling again `ProductDisplayActivity` with of course different values.

**Problem:**

My problem is, if I navigate from `product 1` to the `product list` an then to `product 2` and then try to back-navigate pressing the `back button`, the `Bundle` of `product 1` has the `ProductInfoDescription` of the `product 2`.
I have no idea on how to solve this issue, when calling a new `ProductDisplayActivity` and then `new ProductInfoFragment` shouldn't every fragment have their own `Bundle` with their own value since are different fragments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue in a non optimal way, so if anybody comes up with a better answer I'll be glad to check.

Basically I saved the string "SavedString" into the activity too, so when the Activity gets resumed I call the fragment function to set the text:

```
ProductInfoFragmentListener.DownloadProductInfo(Html.fromHtml(SavedString.getString("SavedString")));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Then I have an activity called ResultsList with a list of products, and on click I start a new intent calling again ProductDisplayActivity with of course different values.

Are you sure you are not messing up terminology here? It sure sounds like it.
EDIT: Well, you don't. By embedding Fragments within an Activity you are putting yourself in position in dealing with double the lifecycles.

1. Make sure you have an activity through which two fragments (List and Info) communicate with each other. These fragments should have interfaces that are implemented by the activity.
2. Pass a Bundle object as arguments to each fragment. Fill info upon building the fragment.
3. You may be better off using FragmentManager.replace() unless you want to show multiple infos.

Comment: `But showing a fragment via launching an activity through a new Intent is not the best idea I imagine.` Could you explain why? Also, the list is not a fragment, it's an activity, as I wrote in my question I navigate from `product activity` to `list activity` and then to `product activity` again.

Comment: With little work you can accommodate multiple screens via encapsulating fragments within a layout. You cannot really put two different activities beside each other. FragmentManager class makes it easier. By putting a fragment into a different activity you are limiting yourself since Fragments are designed to be modular and have lifecycle on their own.